# Does Nurse Joy need to diagnose Pokérus to see the status?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

If you heal your Pokémon at a Pokémon Centre and one of them has the Pokérus virus, Nurse Joy comments on it. Does Nurse Joy need to have diagnosed the presence of Pokérus on your Pokémon before it will show as a status on its Summary screen, or is it just fluff text?

I'm checking the Pokémon I've caught over the course of my adventure for Pokérus (unlikely, as it's rarer than shiny Pokémon, but worth checking), was wondering if it was sufficient to just rattle through the Summary pages of all my Pokémon in the PC, or if I need to withdraw and hand over all my Pokémon to Nurse Joy to diagnose it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, if the pokemon has pokerus, it'll be shown in the [summary screen](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Tv4dMuJVhWRowWPKrTXJ9IOPI3WySwd4NBl4I_4gvTC_YfW8lNQlHDQMXxSlAY6x7CRsIPyUOEqLKr-2VAcMSZTFve9OHpmlIweE4JIkHaVcQ9nj77i8EH-iH5L0t493hB5uwl1aNo8Wt39QCwkVyl_MuXOUWuHY4TGYC2lm0nBOnMFL5IvP7jDMK_DInPg=w297-h495-nc). No need to diagnose it at all.

Comment: While this is true, it's worth noting that the rarity of encountering something with Pokerus is so low that you'd be better off just waiting for it to happen when she tells you or trading with someone who has a Pokemon with Pokerus.

Comment: Cheers! I have Pokémon with Pokérus in Bank but at present Bank transfers aren't possible haha